# Difference between these sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't seem to understand why these two queries return different results for the following task: "Find names and grades of students who only have friends in the same grade. Return the result sorted by grade, then by name within each grade."

Tables here: https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/DB/SQL/asset/socialdata.html

The first query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT h1.name, h1.grade
FROM Highschooler h1, Friend f, Highschooler h2
WHERE h1.ID = f.ID1 AND h2.ID = f.ID2 AND h1.grade = h2.grade
ORDER BY h1.grade, h1.name
```

The second query:

```
select name, grade from Highschooler
where ID not in (
    select ID1 from Highschooler H1, Friend, Highschooler H2
    where H1.ID = Friend.ID1 and Friend.ID2 = H2.ID and H1.grade <> H2.grade)
order by grade, name;
```

The second one returns the expected result, but not the first one. If anyone cares to clarify, Thanks.

Comment: can you be more precise on "but not the first one"? in what way is it unexpected? (if you can show the results or a relavant part, the better)

Comment: What might be more relevant is that neither query answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query applies three filter in the query simultaneously to all data in tables and returns just those entries matching all the filters. The second query firstly does a subquery where it returns rows matching the subquery condition and then all the IDs which are not there are returned, which includes also IDs for which `H1.ID = Friend.ID1` and `Friend.ID2 = H2.ID` do not hold true. You can try something like:

```
select name, grade from Highschooler
where where H1.ID = Friend.ID1 and Friend.ID2 = H2.ID  and ID not in (
    select ID1 from Highschooler H1, Friend, Highschooler H2
    where H1.ID = Friend.ID1 and Friend.ID2 = H2.ID and H1.grade <> H2.grade)
order by grade, name;
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be standard NULL - related behavior . Demo

```
create table tble (ID int, col int);
insert tble(ID, col) 
values (1,1),(2,null),(3,2);

select *
from tble 
where col=1;

select *
from tble 
where ID not in (select t2.ID from tble t2 where t2.col<>1);
```

Because `select t2.ID from tble t2 where t2.col<>1` must not return ID 2 as predicate `NULL <> 1` does not evaluates to TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add further clarification on the first query explanations. The first query results in this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT h1.name, h1.grade FROM Highschooler h1, Friend f, Highschooler h2 WHERE h1.ID = f.ID1 AND h2.ID = f.ID2 AND h1.grade = h2.grade ORDER BY h1.grade, h1.name;
    +-----------+-------+
    | name      | grade |
    +-----------+-------+
    | Cassandra |     9 |
    | Gabriel   |     9 |
    | Jordan    |     9 |
    | Tiffany   |     9 |
    | Andrew    |    10 |
    | Brittany  |    10 |
    | Haley     |    10 |
    | Kris      |    10 |
    | Alexis    |    11 |
    | Gabriel   |    11 |
    | Jessica   |    11 |
    | John      |    12 |
    | Jordan    |    12 |
    | Kyle      |    12 |
    | Logan     |    12 |
    +-----------+-------+
    15 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Since you are performing a cartesian product (by means of selecting the same table `Highschooler` twice), and one of your conditions is `h1.grade = h2.grade`, you are going to retrieve all students that have at least one friend in the same grade. The only student you are not getting is `Austin`, which is the only one that doesn't have any friends in his grade.

The second query is explained in Radek's answer.

I hope this helps.